# What is the general formula for the number sequence $0, 1, 4, 8, 12, 16,\cdots$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to find out the general formula/function for 
\begin{align}
f(1) &= 0 \\
f(2) &= 1 \\
f(3) &= 4 \\
f(4) &= 8 \\
f(5) &= 12 \\
f(6) &= 16
\end{align}

Comment: $f(n)=4n-8$ for $n≥3$, $f(0)=0,f(1)=2$?

Comment: @lulu The most obvious guess! But the intented solution is probably somehing else.

Comment: The list you have is a fine formula.  We have no indication the domain is any larger than $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$

Answer (score 2):

It could be the [Toothpick pyramid](https://oeis.org/A160408), which is
$$
0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 32, 48, 64, 72, 76, 80, 88, \cdots
$$

Comment: Or the toothpick sequence... Thanks [oeis.org](http://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C1%2C2%2C4%2C8%2C12%2C16&language=english&go=Search)

Comment: Learn something every day...thanks!

Comment: awesome sequence. toothpick pyramid with $2$ omitted.

Answer (score 0):

One possible formula:

$$f(n)= \begin{cases} 4(n-2) & n \geq 3 \\ n-1 & n < 3 \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure

$$f(x)=\tfrac1{120} x^5 - \tfrac{1}{8}x^4 + \tfrac{13}{24}x^3 + \tfrac18 x^2 - \tfrac{31}{20}x + 1$$

Answer (score 0):

Clearly it is
$$ f(x) = 4(x-2) + \frac{4-3x}{\Gamma(3-x)} $$